# Are there any good strategies to bilinear sample from a tiled image?

Tags: c++, c, image, optimization

When doing a bilinear sample of an image one needs the 4 neighbor pixels. This is easy for an image that is linear in memory. 
However, if the image is made of individual tiles in memory, in the worst case each of the four samples is in a different tile. 
What are some strategies to make this fast? Assume that tiles are powers of two squares. In most cases a gather should stay within one tile.

There is one w x h array T of tile pointers, each tile is a raw array of k x k pixels. How to make a fast Gather (x,y,dest) function that returns the four pixels at (x,y),(x+1,y),(x,y+1),(x+1,y+1)?

What if the tiles are not raw pointers but objects that potentially need to be paged in? So there needs to be a test if(T[o]==0) PageIn(o);

Also edges of the whole image should clamp, so value(-1,y)==value(0,y) etc.

This is a pretty open ended question. I know how to do it. I am looking for tricks and tips on how to do it fast.

Comment: Can you just make the tiles 2 px wide and taller? Say if you have 16x16 tiles, makes them 18x18 tiles where the new rows and columns come from the neighbourhood tiles. You still consider them as 16x16 tiles but when it comes to interpolating border pixels you have the neighbourhood data just loaded in the additional rows/columns.

Comment: @MargaretBloom I converted your comment to an answer. Actually, I have used this idea in the past (for 1-bit pixels), so didn't even read your comment before I wrote my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Have your tiles store redundant pixels - that is, store pixels near a tile boundary in both neighboring tiles (or actually in 4 tiles if the pixel is near a tile's corner).

This completely eliminates the overhead of reading pixels (including near the boundary) at the cost of wasted memory. Also, writing pixels is harder - writing an individual pixel may require updating up to 4 tiles. However, if you calculate an entire image, generating the redundant pixels is a uniform procedure.

You might want to choose a particular size for a tile. For example, width = 62 pixels (when pixel = byte); after adding two redundant pixels, the width is equal to a cache line (assuming it's 64 bytes).

If using bicubic interpolation, add 2 redundant pixels from each side.

Comment: I actually experimented with that. But what about a filter with a large footprint like a gaussian instead of bilinear? In the end you are just shifting the problem. I agree that your solution is a good one for the question as written - but not in the spirit of it. Another big problem with duplicating borders is mip-map like techniques. Power of two tiles downsample in 2x2 boxes nicely.

Comment: Actually, your answer is very helpful in a http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Rubber%20ducking rubber duck way. If I really only need to take a bilinear sample it absolutely is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can always pre-allocate pointers to *lines within a tile*. Sort them into a big array of pointers in a way that you can get to the tile scanline by accessing the pointer array

```
char* ptr [numTilesH][numTilesV * tileHeight];

// ... fill the pointer array with pointers to the beginning of each 
// scanline in a tile...

// ...assume 256 grey scales
unsigned char getPixel (int x, int y) {
   int hTileNr = x / tileWidth;
   int hTileOffs = x % tileWidth;

   char * pixelPtr = ptr [hTileNr][y];
   return pixelPtr [hTileOfs];
}
```

In this case, the optimisation is a typical memory vs. CPU trade-in. As you can see here, access to a pixel is one division with remainder, and two array accesses. Should be blazingly fast, once you have set up the pointer arrays. The more tiles you have, however, the more memory you'll need for the scanline pointers - Maybe up to a point where the pointer arrays simply become too expensive.